# PHP Cookie won't parse

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to send the value of a cookie through a function, but it doesn't seem to be parsing.  Here is a snippet of code I'm using:

```
function displayForm(){
   setcookie("site_Referral", $_GET['rid'], time()+10000);
   $ref_cookie = $_COOKIE['site_Referral'];
   $joinProc = new joinProcessor();
   return $joinProc->process($ref_cookie);
}
```

When I check my database there's no value being put through at all.  If I change it to:

```
function displayForm(){
   setcookie("site_Referral", $_GET['rid'], time()+10000);
   $ref_cookie = 'foo';
   $joinProc = new joinProcessor();
   return $joinProc->process($ref_cookie);
}
```

The value 'foo' is entered just fine.  I've also tried checking to see whether the cookie is set properly and it is - it appears on the Web Developer toolbar and when I write `return $ref_cookie`, it displays the correct value.  It also doesn't work if I just use the `$_GET` value.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try letting the program have some time between making the cookie and accessing the cookie.

Comment: Is the query string value of 'rid' set?

Comment: @judda Yeah - I'm pointing towards join.php?rid=example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that [`setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie) actually doesn't set anything. It should be called "sendcookie" as it is only concerned with crafting the Set-Cookie HTTP header. It does not store the value into the $_COOKIE array (which is only set when PHP first parses the current request.)

```
setcookie("abc", "xyz");    // Sends cookie header
print $_COOKIE["abc"];      // Read  existing cookie of CURRENT request
```

The $_COOKIE array will be updated on the next request, after you have setcookied it.

Use the temporary veriable directly in your code snippet:

```
function displayForm(){
   setcookie("site_Referral", $ref_cookie = $_GET['rid'], time()+10000);
   ...
```

Comment: So would it be something like: `function displayForm(){
   setcookie("site_Referral", $ref_cookie = $_GET['rid'], time()+10000);
   $joinProc = new joinProcessor();
   return $joinProc->process($ref_cookie);
}` ?

Comment: I worked it out. I created a proxy page which sets the cookie and then redirects it to the join page. This way the cookie's fully set before the join script loads. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

As [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) states, `setcookie()` defines a cookie to be sent along with other HTTP headers.  This means that it does not immediately set a cookie in `_COOKIE`.  You can access it on the next page load assuming that no other headers (including any whitespace) have been output before calling `setcookie()`.